# Remove an empty directory with ssh

Tags: ssh

Why rm dirname doesn't work ? It says it's a directory, well that I know :) but I want to delete it not even recursively as it is empty.

Comment: The answer below is correct, but there's also no harm in doing `rm -rf` on an empty directory; it's identical to `rmdir`.  Most of the time, if I don't care about what's in a directory, I'll use `rm -rf` rather than worry about whether or not it might be empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you need to use `rmdir`?

Answer (score 1):

```
rm -d my_directory
```

from 'man rm':

> -d          Attempt to remove directories as well as other types of files.

Comment: I tried with -d it still says the same message